# Why do I can't access selection 1 after using it in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Hi greetings to everyone, I am currently seeking for a help in my code. In the first loop my selection 1 works but after the process of 1 there will be a question if you want to continue or not. If I choose the 'No' and entered the selection 1 again, the loop won't accept it but it accepts 2, 3 and 4. Thanks for the help if anyone is willing to help.

```
student_id = 0
correct_answers = 0
passed_students = 0
failed_students = 0
isRunning = True
isTakingExam = True
isRetakeCorrect = True
class_record = []
students_exam_answer = []
answer_list = ['D', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A',
               'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B',
               'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C',
               'D', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A',
               'A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C']

try:
    while isRunning:
        print('\nExamination System v1.0\n\n'
              '[1] Take the exam\n'
              '[2] Check my exam\n'
              '[3] Display class record\n'
              '[4] Exit\n')

        service = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

        if 0 < service < 5:
            if service == 1:
                while isTakingExam:
                    # Storing the Students Name
                    student_name = input('Enter your full name: ')
                    students_exam_answer.append([student_name])

                    # Storing the Students Answer
                    for count in range(len(answer_list)):
                        student_answer = input(f'Enter Answer For {count + 1}: ')
                        students_exam_answer[student_id].append(student_answer.upper())

                    # Checking the Students Answer
                    for answers in range(len(answer_list)):
                        if students_exam_answer[student_id][answers + 1] == answer_list[answers]:
                            correct_answers += 1

                    # Checking if the Student passed or failed
                    if correct_answers >= 15:
                        print(f'\n{student_name} passed the exam. Score: {correct_answers} out of 25')
                        passed_students += 1
                    else:
                        print(f'\n{student_name} failed the exam. Score: {correct_answers} out of 25')
                        failed_students += 1

                    print(f'\nExam Status:\n'
                          f'Correct Answers: {correct_answers}\n'
                          f'Incorrect Answers: {25 - correct_answers}\n')

                    # Resetting variables that is needed in the next loop
                    class_record.append([student_name, correct_answers])
                    student_id += 1
                    correct_answers = 0
                    isRetakeCorrect = True
                    while isRetakeCorrect:
                        retake = input('\nNew Examinee? [Y/N]: ')
                        if retake.isalpha() and retake.upper() == 'Y':
                            isRetakeCorrect = False
                            isTakingExam = True

                        elif retake.isalpha() and retake.upper() == 'N':
                            isRetakeCorrect = False
                            isTakingExam = False
                        else:
                            print('\nInvalid input. Please try again.\n')

            elif service == 2:
                student_name = input('Enter your full name: ')
                for students in range(len(students_exam_answer)):
                    if student_name in students_exam_answer[students]:
                        print(f'\nScore: {class_record[students][1]}')
                        for answers in range(len(students_exam_answer[students]) - 1):
                            print(f'Number {answers + 1}: {students_exam_answer[students][answers + 1]} '
                                  f'(Correct Answer: {answer_list[answers]})')

                input('\nPress Enter key to continue...')

            elif service == 3:
                print(f'\nPassed Students: {passed_students}\n'
                      f'Failed Students: {failed_students}\n')
                if passed_students == 0 and failed_students == 0:
                    print('No record found.')
                else:
                    for record in class_record:
                        print(f'Name: {class_record[class_record.index(record)][0]}\n'
                              f'Score: {class_record[class_record.index(record)][1]}\n')

                input('\nPress Enter key to continue...')

            elif service == 4:
                exit(0)

        else:
            print('\nInvalid input. Please try again.\n')

except ValueError:
    print('\nInvalid input. Please try again.')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with the variable `isTakingExam`, when user answers `No` the code sets this variable to `False` to exit the loop, maybe you should set it to `True` just before the loop:

```
...
if service == 1:
    isTakingExam=True
    while isTakingExam: 
    ...
```

Comment: Hey bro, It worked but can you explain it more further to me on why it worked?

Comment: At the first time, user choose `1` and the code executes the part after `if service == 1` correctly (the variable `isTakingExam` has already initialized to `True` at the begining of the program). 
Then, if user answers `No` (not retake the exam) the code sets `isTakingExam` to `False` to exit that loop. 
Then, if user choose again `1`  the value of the `isTakingExam` remains `False` and the `while isTakingExam` is equal to `while False`.

Comment: Oww I Get, Thank you so much Sir for the help